# reading a huge csv file using cudf

Tags: cudf

I am trying to read a huge csv file CUDF but gets memory issues.

```
import cudf
cudf.set_allocator("managed")
cudf.__version__
user_wine_rate_df = cudf.read_csv('myfile.csv',
                                 sep = "\t",
                                 parse_dates = ['created_at'])


'0.17.0a+382.gbd321d1e93'

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  parallel_for failed: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I remove `cudf.set_allocator("managed")`
I get

```
MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error at: /opt/conda/envs/rapids/include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp:69: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory
```

I am using CUDF through `rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda11.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04-py3.8`

I wonder whar could be the reason of hitting memory, while I can read this big file with pandas

**Update

I installed *dask_cudf*

and used `dask_cudf.read_csv('myfile.csv')` - but still get the

`parallel_for failed: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

If the file you are reading is larger than the memory available then you will observe an OOM(Out Of Memory) error as cuDF runs on a sigle GPU.
In order to read files which are very large I would recommend using [dask_cudf](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/dask-cudf.html).

Comment: Thanks, I just installed and used dask_cudf.read_csv('example_output/*.csv') - but still get the  parallel_for failed: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered - thanks for your help

Comment: Please can you provide more information by posting your client setup code

Comment: I have a RTX2070 super using  rapidsai/rapidsai:cuda11.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04-py3.8 docker which I can execute the example code in the github page. what sort of information should I provide you here ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this blog](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/reading-larger-than-memory-csvs-with-rapids-and-dask-e6e27dfa6c0f) by Nick Becker on reading larger than GPU memory files.  It should get you on your way.